# When I parent my model with a Bvh animation the arms cross? why is that?

Tags: rigging, motion-capture

So when I parent my model with a bvh file and then I start the animation the arms of the model crosses, Why is that? [image]

[image]

Comment: Could be a problem with the coordinate axes. Which software wrote the BVH file? And can you share it with us?

Comment: Can you provide an image of the rest pose.  Is it a T-pose?    @dr.Sybren given the 10_04 name, (kick soccer ball - walk), assume it's some flavour of CMU [cgspeed](https://sites.google.com/a/cgspeed.com/cgspeed/motion-capture/cmu-bvh-conversion)

Comment: I got the bvh file from https://sites.google.com/a/cgspeed.com/cgspeed/motion-capture/cmu-bvh-conversion

Comment: The animation works fine before I parent it, once I parent it then the model crosses the arms.

Comment: Can you please  edit question and describe the steps you took to parent to rig.  A screen shot with rig in rest pose, and with rig  expanded in outliner.  Or [upload file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: It won't let me upload any of the files, but my steps are I import my mesh and bvh file. Once their imported I put the rig in Rest Position then I go into edit mode for the rig so I can match it up with my mesh. Once it's matched up, I go into object mode and parent it with automatic weights.

Comment: Yes the Rest position and pose position are T-Pose. But I have gotten other rigs to work so im thinking it could just been the bvh file.

Comment: What are you parenting it to?

Comment: I Parent the model to the rig with automatic weights

Comment: If you edit the rig to match your mesh, you naff up the action.  That is why the arms are crossed.  The action is an offset from the rest pose.  Either edit your mesh to match the rig's rest pose, or use something like [in this answer which fixes animation to fit new rest pose](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91301/transfer-a-rig-from-motionbuilder-to-blender/91826#91826)

Comment: Another solution that I found that works for any mesh is the makehuman bvh add-on for blender

Answer (score 1):

So the answer to my question is, because my model was not in a complete t stance when I Parent it,  the animation starts on t stance which mess up my model. If this makes any sense lol. So the answer is make sure your model and bvh rig matches up before you parent it.