# Assigning Mesh into Pose Bone position not Rest Bone

Tags: armature, bones

I have this situation where I got BVH mocap animation that looks fine throughout the animation. Start pose bone is actually correct, but the Rest Bone is stupid as all the limbs etc are simply all over the place.

I have now needing to attach / assign 3D Mesh character that is already good in position and matching the first frame of the Pose Bone, but this does not work because the Rest Bone is out of whack...

Is there in anyway I could attach or match Rest Bone into Post Bone without changing the animation.

I thought that Apply Pose Bone into Rest Bone would do the job, but not...

I am using BVH of this Flamenco dance:
http://dancedb.eu/main/performances

Comment: It's weird that similar question asked so many times but no easy way, just hack like:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97415/how-to-define-the-rest-position-in-a-bvh-file-converted-from-an-fbx

Comment: Been answered here:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97415/how-to-define-the-rest-position-in-a-bvh-file-converted-from-an-fbx But needs updated script for Blender 2.80.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define the rest position in a BVH file (converted from an FBX)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97415/how-to-define-the-rest-position-in-a-bvh-file-converted-from-an-fbx)